# How to reverse y axis with `geom_raster()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to show the y axis from `a` to `d` instead of from `d` to `a`. `scale_y_discrete()` does not work in this case. Does anybody know how to reverse? Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
m=3
n=4
dat=expand.grid(x=letters[seq_len(m)], y=letters[seq_len(n)])
dat$z=rnorm(m*n)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_raster()
```

Comment: Could you just reorder your data before inputting it into `ggplot`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, its best to use `set.seed()` so people can reproduce your results exactly. That said, you have two options: (1) reorder the factor levels in the `ggplot` call or (2) reorder the factor levels in the data. In general, I prefer to edit the data before hand since it simplifies your `ggplot` call and gives you more control over what's going on.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
m=3;n=4
dat=expand.grid(x=letters[seq_len(m)], y=letters[seq_len(n)])
dat$z=rnorm(m*n)
```

**Option 1. Reordering in ggplot:**

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_raster() + 
         scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$y)))
```

**Option 2. Reordering in data:**

```
dat$y <- factor(dat$y, levels = rev(levels(dat$y)))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_raster()
```

Both should produce:[image]

Comment: Depending on your particular code, for option `limits=rev(data$y)` maybe what you need.